# Recommend a NoSQL database to replace this MySQL database containing large objects and many attributes

Tags: java, mongodb, performance-testing, partitioning, nosql

I'm looking for an alternative database for MySQL (Engine = MyISAM).

My Java application stores large objects with 250 - 300 attributes each.  There are about 500 millions objects on a single MySQL server.  Avoiding unnecessary joins, it uses vertical partition, performed manually.  There are nearly 250 tables for storing attribute values, which are also indexed.  MySQL performs slowly when querying  particular attributes (querying 5 Attributes means 5 joins).

Recommend a NoSQL-Database to increase the speed of the query performance (range queries, exact match queries and combination of them).

MongoDB seems a good alternative to storing these objects in a single collection, unfortunately MongoDB can only index a maximum of 64 attributes per collection, which means I would have to split the object values as well. MongoDB also doesn't provide a capability for joining the collection server-side.

1. Does anybody know how to "join" multiple collection using MongoDB / Java using dbref / manual references?
2. If no, are there other NoSQL-databases for storing large object with ca. 250 attributes, as described above?

Requirements:

- No transactions required
- users have to see just the attributes they queried, not the entire object
- single database server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a restriction of 64 indexes, but you can do something like following.

In the 'attr' array you can put your 250-300 attributes and then index on 'attr'. And then you can query on the any attr elements.

But let me remind you, the size of the this index will be huge. There will be 1 index entry for each element in 'attr' field. But you can profile the query performance.

```
test:Mongo > db.abhi.insert({ name : 'abhi', attr : [ { attr1 : 'val1' }, { attr2 : 'val2'}, {attr3 : 'val3'} ]})

test:Mongo > db.abhi.ensureIndex({attr : 1})
test:Mongo > db.abhi.find({attr : {attr1 : 'val1'}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor attr_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "attr" : [
            [
                {
                    "attr1" : "val1"
                },
                {
                    "attr1" : "val1"
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "bdvlpabhishekk:27017"
}
```

Comment: I had the same idea at first but i guess it wont increase the query performance because user usually picks just a few attributes (5-8) in there query. But i can check out the performance in comparison with MySQL as well as the index size.

Comment: Unfortunately the index on the nested attribute is to large for mongodb even for 100 attribute values per object.

Comment: Ok i just separated the the attribute values into 60 embedded documents so that each nested document has around 2-4 attributes, and indexed each nested document. It seems to speed up the performance. At least now its so fast as mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I personally worked ( and contribued to ) with OrientDB but there are many nosql, he don't have limit  in number of fields

i can suggest a couple of website where find out more:

[nosql database](http://nosql-database.org/)

[oriendb vs mongodb](http://vschart.com/compare/orientdb/vs/mongodb)

Comment: Thanks oriendb sounds good like an good alternative. I will check out the limitations in terms of indexing.

Comment: Ok orientDB seems to be very advanced in terms of the query language. But unfortunately it has a bad query performance in comparison with cassandra and mongodb. And also the indexing process takes a long time. I'm using the documtent database storage engine (ODatabaseDocumentTx) and i also configurated the server as it is recommended on the official website of orientdb developers. Maybe i overread something in terms of performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

AerospikeDB is a good solution for this

It's commonly deployed with billions of objects, so 500M won't be a sweat

The indexes will be large, but the in-memory representation of the indexes are fairly compact. The size of the index will depend on the amount of selectivity of individual index values on a given attribute. If you know the selectivity, you can calculate the exact amount of memory to keep from paging, and since it's SSD optimized you get much better performance than you do with other NoSQL databases on SSD.

Storing this number of columns works great, and doesn't require a join internally.

http://aerospike.com/

[caveat: I wrote part of Aerospike, but I still like it]

Comment: Ok thanks sounds great. But can i also expect better performance on a usual hard disk or is it designed for flash storage?

Comment: It is designed from the ground up as an in-memory database, so it can store transaction logs on a rotational disk, but data and indexes must be in RAM or Flash.